# Nested for loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I was just wondering if I could get some guidance on an issue I am having with nested for loops in javascript.

I currently have the following nested for loop in place

```
for (var i = 0; i <= score; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        var stsc = '<img src="./images/star.png"/>';
    }
}
```

The aim is to get the variable stsc to show the number of stars depending on the count of the score variable.

Currently, it will only show 1 star no matter what the value of score is. I have tried adding stsc outside of the nested loop to no avail. No matter what I do it will show nothing other than 1 star.

Could you point me in the right direction as to how to get it to show the correct number of stars (3 stars if score is 3, 0 stars if score is 0 etc...)

Thanks everyone

Comment: Why do you need a nested for loop? Looks to me like a normal for loop from `0` to `score` should just do fine. Learn about string concatenation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators.

Comment: I was always taught that a nested loop was needed for such situations. I tried it with just the one loop but I still only got the 1 star to display

Comment: You have to add value to stsc variable. At first you have to init variable to empty string before loop: stsc = ''; Then use stsc += '<img...';

Comment: I assume that there's other code that you're not showing us?  Because you're assigning the string to your (very local) variable `stsc`, over and over, and not doing anything with it.

Comment: Hi Ann, there is a lot more code that I have. It is just this one particular issue that I am having. If I display the variable then it displays the correct number, it just wont add to the stsc variable when I want to show the correct number of stars. E.g. If I score = 3 then if I just show score or just show j then it shows 3, but will only show 1 instance of the star image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var stsc="";
var score=0;
for (var i = 1; i <= score; i++)
{

        stsc = stsc +'<img src="./images/star.png"/>';

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5Btd/1295/

Comment: Hi Vinit, out of those that I tried this did the trick. Thanks so much for your help. Thank you everyone else too

Comment: @felix: it is strange. If I tried it with the += it would stop the rest of the code executing. Really strange since I can use += for integer variables. Thanks for your answers though

Answer (score 2):

You just need a normal `for` loop and [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators):

```
var stsc = '';

for (var i = 0; i < score; i++) {
    stsc += '<img src="./images/star.png"/>';
}
```

Think about it like this: You want to create `n` stars, where `n` is the value of the score. Hence you have to repeat the process of creating the HTML string `n` times. That's what a `for` loop is doing, repeating something until a condition is fulfilled. And instead of *overwriting* the variable in each iteration, you have to *add* to it.

Comment: Hi Felix, when I try this it stops the rest of the code from displaying. I am using jQuery to display the results and this stops the whole script dead in its tracks

Comment: Since I don't know the rest of your code, there is not much I can help you with. You could create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Make sure `score` is defined. Have a look at the console for errors.

Comment: @Chris and double check that you wrote the `for` loop correctly and specifically that "i" is being incremented properly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need *any* `for` loops:

```
var stsc = score === 0 ? "" : new Array(score + 1).join("<img src=./images/star.png>");
```